# "'NotebookFormatter' object has no attribute 'get_result'" error when querying from BigQuery into Jupyter?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

Per [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter) I'm trying to load in some sample data from BigQuery. Even though the data loads successfully, I get this error at the very end. If I run `%bigquery x` as the 1st line to store the results as a variable, I can verify I'm stilling getting a 15 row pandas data frame by running type(x) and len(x), but calling x itself still results in an error.. Help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this. At least it worked for me

```
!pip uninstall numpy
!pip uninstall pandas

!pip install --user numpy
!pip install --user  pandas
```

Comment: Yeah, for me too! (Although, I have a situation different from the one in question)